# Deleting appended element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a simple todo-application but the elements who been created with jQuery, can't be deleted with the shortkey I've setup. The shortkey I've made works on the first element (and other elements that are on the page from the beginning) but elements that came into the DOM via jQuery, can't be deleted.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('textarea.todo').focus(function () {
            $(this).elastic();
        });

        $('textarea.todo').focusout(function () {
            $(this).animate({ height: "2em" }, 500);
            $(this).scrollTop(0);
        });

        $('#addTodo').click(function(){
            $('<textarea class="todo" rows="1"></textarea>').appendTo('#todos');
        });

        $('.todo').bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+d', function(){
            $(this).fadeOut('Slow');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        Simple<span id="alt">TODO</span>
    </div>
    <div id="todos">
        <textarea class="todo" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="left"><img src="PlusSign.png" id="addTodo"/></div>
        <div class="right">HELP</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Links to external sites can be a useful *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question itself*. (If it's a lot of code, you'll have to create a minimal test case that replicates the problem.) Stack Overflow is meant not just to be a resource for you now, but for others with a similar problem in the future. External links can be modified, deleted, moved, etc., rendering the question and its answers precisely useless for people in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.todo').bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+d', function(){
                                    $(this).fadeOut('Slow');
                    });
```

Here use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `bind`. In this case newly created elements will be automatically subscribed.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.todo', function(e){    
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.keyCode == 68)
            $(this).fadeOut('Slow');
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/FgZaR/3/

Comment: This answer makes the element react to alt, ctrl or D. Edit: not only those but all keyboard presses removes the elements.

Comment: It would be nice if you tell the poster why the problem happened on the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is basically that the element was added AFTER the handler was added (the element just wasn't there), in this case and depending on your jQuery version, there are a few options you can use.

- Latest versions use 'on' http://api.jquery.com/on/
- Previous versions use both 'delegate' and 'live' http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ or http://api.jquery.com/live/

That will register events even if they are added after you made the initial binding.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply that when you add an Element with your AddTodo method you don't attach the shortcut event on it.

```
$('#addTodo').click(function(){
    $('<textarea class="todo" rows="1"></textarea>').appendTo('#todos').bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+d', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('Slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this and it worked:

```
            $('#addTodo').click(function(){
            $('<textarea class="todo" rows="1"></textarea>').appendTo('#todos');
            $('.todo').bind('keydown', 'alt+ctrl+d', function(){
                $(this).fadeOut('Slow');
            });
        });
```

Probably not the best solution but it worked atleast.